# How to spawn an entity with the same velocity as another entity?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to summon an arrow with the same velocity as an egg that has just been thrown. I know about the NBT tag `Motion:[x,y,z]`, but I have no idea how to match that with the velocity of another entity.

I tried to just have the arrow be constantly be teleported to the egg, but it doesn't land where the egg lands.

Comment: Teleporting does not copy velocity? Now I have to edit my answer to another question in this forum...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can transfer NBT data from one entity to another in newer versions of minecraft. To replace all eggs with arrows with the same `Motion`-tag, you could use these three commands, executed in a repeating command block and then two chain command blocks:

```
/execute at @e[type=egg] run summon minecraft:arrow ~ ~ ~
/execute as @e[type=minecraft:arrow] at @s run data modify entity @s Motion set from entity @e[type=egg,distance=0,limit=1] Motion
/kill @e[type=egg]
```

The first command summons an arrow at the position of every egg.

The second command sets the `Motion`-tag of every arrow to the same value as any egg that is in exactly the same position.

The third command kills all eggs.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is: **you can't**.

---

The longer answer is: You still can't, but here is why:
You can't transfer NBT data from one entity to another. Normally you might be able to work around that by detecting the NBT data in the first entity with a few hardcoded values, and then giving that same tag to the other entity.
This however won't work for the `Motion` tag since that incorporates three double values, and a typical Motion tag looks something like this: `Motion[0.17361829472d,1.38572958294d,0.72483746234d]` *(good luck finding that one with hardcoded values)*

Comment: Do you think that it will be possible to do the midair-replacement in 1.13 with the ^ ^ ^ coordinates?

Comment: form what it looks like now, you'll be able to copy the facing but not other NBT data. using `^ ^ ^` you could however teleport the arrows along the way they are supposed to, maybe that will help. But I really can't say anthing for sure yet.

Comment: In 1.14 you can copy NBT.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder. in 1.13 and 1.14 the answer above wouldn't be correct anymore. I'll try to find the time to edit in the current possibilities